# How to improve Lottie animation performance on android

Tags: java, android, lottie

How can I improve the performance of animations playing on older devices? I've tried using an anonymous `Handler` and `myLooper` thread but the app still lags on older deviced, how can I fix this?

I tried to wait for the animation to finish before resuming other processes but whenever I tried that using `animationName.isRunning` the app just freezes.

**code (running in a fragment)**:

```
if(this.confetti.isHardwareAccelerated()) {
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
                    confetti.playAnimation();
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

try using images instead of vectors that might help with complex vectors